# Descobrindo qual valor é maior

Tags: php

Segue o código abaixo:

```
<?php
        $timeZone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
        $dataInicio = new DateTime('2016-06-14', $timeZone);//dataFinal do evento
        $dataFinal = new DateTime('2016-06-25', $timeZone);//dataFinal do evento
        $diadasemana = "16/06";
        if (($diadasemana >= $dataInicio->format('d/m')) && ($diadasemana <= $dataFinal->format('d/m'))) {
            //16/06 => //14/06 && 16/06 < 25/06
            echo 'Entrei no IF';
        } else {
            echo 'não somos igauis';
        }
//retorno Entrei no IF
```

Como o PHP consegue interpretar qual valor é maior?

Comment: diadasemana é igual a datainicio e menor do que datafinal. 
E você esta perguntando exatamente isso. Então é logico que ele entre na primeira condição e execute a linha 'Entrei no IF'

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo isso é óbvio, estou querendo que se possível me expliquem como o php consegue entender qual é maior ou menor.  Ex : //16/06 => //14/06 && 14/06 < 25/06

Comment: Como você consegue saber que 16 é maior do que 14 e que é menor do 25? Fazendo conta. Certo? O PHP também.

Comment: Pode dar pau seu código, não é uma boa ideia. É preferível usar `new DateTime < new DateTime('-1 day')`. é melhor já usar o próprio mecanismo do PHP

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo beleza, falou mais uma coisa óbvia. Cara, se for para ser ignorante desse jeito, nem comente. Você não é pago e nem obrigado a fazer isso. Não estou só comparando antes da / e sim a string inteiro. Presta atenção

Comment: Desculpe-me se pareci ignorante. Não quis ser rude. Acontece que a pergunta era obvia demais e não havia outra alternativa, a não ser, ser obvio. De qualquer forma: desculpa aí.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Indo por partes

O código vai sendo executado em partes. Primeiro ele calcula algumas partes para chegar em um resultado booliano:

```
$dataInicio->format('d/m') //resulta em "14/06"

"16/06" >= "14/06" //resulta em true porque são iguais

$dataFinal->format('d/m') //resulta em "25/06"

"14/06" <= "25/06" //resulta em true porque 1 é menor que 2, só olha o primeiro caractere
```

O operador `&&` é um *and*, então a resultado será `true` sempre que os dois operandos sejam `true`, e `false` em todas as outras situações. Isto é [álgebra booleana](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81lgebra_booliana) básica.

O PHP trata o número 0 como `false` e os demais números como `true`.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/m9A1Eg). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dafwsdfr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/Comparing.php).

Note o resultado da sub-expressão lógica que dá 1, que é o mesmo que `true`.

## Fluxo do `if`

Como o resultado final é um `true` o fluxo do código entra no primeiro bloco de código, ignorando o segundo, afinal eles são excludentes. Depois de executar o primeiro bloco ele vai para a instrução seguinte ao bloco completo do `if/else`. Se o resultado tivesse sido `false`, o segundo bloco (após o `else`) teria sido executado seguindo para a próxima instrução, mas o primeiro bloco seria completamente ignorado.

O `if` é justamente um comando de controle de fluxo de execução. Sua função é decidir qual bloco executar (há casos que só existe um bloco, ou pode ter vários blocos) de acordo com o valor da expressão condicional colocada nele.

O cálculo das partes dentro do `if` (a condição), apesar de muito comum, é praticamente um acidente. Este cálculo poderia ter sido feito fora do `if` e só o resultado dele sendo usado.

Uma expressão lógica (booleana, que resulta em `false` ou `true`) gera um resultado como outro qualquer, é possível guardar em variável ou fazer o que desejar, assim como dá para fazer com números, textos e outros tipos de objetos. No caso do PHP isso fica até mais óbvio porque no fundo o resultado é até um número 0 ou 1 para tratar os dois resultados possíveis, respectivamente. Algumas pessoas não compreendem isso e acabam achando que o booleano só pode ser usado dentro de um `if`, `while` ou algo do tipo. Isso está longe da verdade. Ele é um dado como outro qualquer.

Por isso eu sempre falo que programar é entender como cada mínima parte do código funciona e não ficar reproduzindo códigos achados na internet ou outro lugar. É importante ser curioso, perguntar o que não sabe, como foi feito aqui.

## Comparação de *strings*

Note que comparar números como *strings* pode ser problemático. Então se comparar "5/5" com "20/5", o segundo será menor, poque o caractere "2" vem antes do caractere "5". A comparação é feita caractere por caractere, ele não tenta interpretar o texto e tratar como um número ou data. Só dá certo se as escalas são iguais, as posições dos algarismos são as mesmas e o texto numérico começa da maior grandeza para a menor (veja abaixo).

No seu exemplo as comparações feitas são `16/06` com `14/06` (o primeiro caractere é igual, mas não dá para ter certeza se tudo é igual ainda, o segundo caractere é maior que o segundo do outro texto, já dá para ter certeza que tudo é maior e nem precisa continuar) e depois na outra comparação: `1` (primeiro caractere de "14/06") com `2` (primeiro caractere de "25/06"), a comparação é otimizada, já dá para saber que 1 é menor que 2 e o que quer que venha depois não faz diferença mais.

A comparação é feita em modo de curto-circuito, ou seja, quando ele já puder ter um resultado definitivo ele não continua comparando. Se quer saber se dois textos são iguais, e já a comparação do primeiro caractere de um texto com o primeiro caractere do outro já é diferente, não tem porque continuar comparando.

O mesmo ocorre quando se procura o menor. Se o primeiro caractere já estabelece qual é o menor, não tem porque continuar avaliando o resto.

#### Comparação de números e outros objetos

Se fosse uma comparação com números, aí a comparação seria mais matemática mesmo, comparando bits, algo que o processador já sabe fazer e não precisa de nenhum algoritmo especial. Na verdade a comparação de bits é feita de forma muito semelhante ao que mostrei na *string*, claro que é feito de forma muito mais eficiente, provavelmente em um passo único do processador.

Na verdade mesmo a comparação dos caracteres no fundo são números, a comparação ocorrerá bit a bit (de acordo com o processador), afinal o conceito de caractere já é um conceito mais abstrato ainda. Haverá um número que nós vemos como caractere de acordo com uma tabela previamente conhecida por nós, mas internamente são só bits. A diferença da comparação de um número puro e um teto que tem números é que o primeiro é feito atomicamente pelo processador (na maior parte das vezes, isso pode ser um pouco mais complicado) e o texto preciso comparar cada algarismo individualmente, o que pode mudar sua grandeza dependendo da sua posição no texto.

Se os objetos comparados fossem datas a comparação provavelmente seria numérica também. Internamente datas são números, em geral é a quantidade de segundos ou outra escala de tempo à partir de um determinado momento. Então fica bem fácil.

## Conclusão

Seu código pode dar resultados indesejados facilmente. Quando precisa mesmo comparar datas ou outros tipos de objetos como texto é fácil resolver este tipo de problema, é matemática pura.

Coloque a parte mais significativa na frente. Em data o mês deve vir antes do dia, já que mês é algo maior, tem mais significado que dia. Ano viria antes de mês. Se tivesse horário, ele viria depois do dia, e a ordem seria hora, minuto, segundo e eventualmente parte fracionária.

Claro que ambos textos precisam estar no mesmo formato pra dar certo.

Lembre-se que se tiver qualquer tipo de formatação extra, como a barra de separação, deve estar sempre no mesmo lugar. Idealmente nem deveria ter isto, se possível.

Neste caso o maior problema é o dia estar na frente do mês. Se puder garantir que sempre seria usado um `format('m/d')` a comparação até funcionaria sempre.

Comment: Consegui entender, obrigado. Na verdade eu só perguntei por dúvida mesmo. Não irei aplicar em nada.